# How to add next page loop scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

Here is my code. Right now it can scrape information from only one page. How I will add page loop?

```
  import scrapy


class P1Spider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'p1'
    allowed_domains = ['www.visit.ferienmesse.ch']
    start_urls = ['https://www.visit.ferienmesse.ch/de/aussteller']

    def parse(self, response):

        for data in response.xpath('//ul[@class="ngn-search-list ngn-mobile-filter"]/li'):
            yield {
                'Link': response.urljoin(data.xpath('.//h2[@class="ngn-content-box-title"]/a/@href').get()),
                'Title': data.xpath('//h2[@class="ngn-content-box-title"]/a/bdi/text()').get(),
                'Address': data.xpath('.//span[@class="ngn-hallname"]/text()').get(),
                'Code': data.xpath('.//span[@class="ngn-stand"]/text()').get()
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

just add this code below and hope it will work.

```
 next_page = response.css('.pagination li.arrow a[rel="next"]::attr(href)').get()

    if next_page:
        yield scrapy.Request(url=response.urljoin(next_page), callback=self.parse)
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider inheriting from [`scrapy.CrawlSpider`](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#crawlspider) instead of `scrapy.Spider`. It does the job of finding and crawling links for you. You just need to give it a set of rules that determine which links to follow and it'll take care of yielding the appropriate Requests, so you can just focus on yielding the scraped content.